# where the files of localStorage of tauri app?

Tags: rust, tauri

we know if I use a browser, I can use local storage to store some keys/values.
but tauri also can use local storage.
so, where is the files of local-Storage of tauri app ?

Comment: That depends on what platform you're building for.  Did you look in  `~/.config`,`~/Library/Application Support` or `~/AppData/Local`?  Those are the standard places for any application

Comment: if you need files, why not just use the `store` plugin? https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri-plugin-store